# Getting certain values from two-dimensional list using lists of indexes / indices

Tags: python-3.x

I have a two dimensional list:

```
myList = [[0,1,2,3],
 [4,5,6,7],
 [8,9,10,11]]
```

I then have a separate two dimensional list of indexes I want from `myList`

```
myIdxs = [[0,2],
 [1,3],
 [0,1]]
```

Is there a 'pythonic' way to get those values, so I end up with a list like this:

```
newList = [[0,2],
 [5,7],
 [8,9]
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using `zip` and list comprehension

**Ex:**

```
myList = [[0,1,2,3],
 [4,5,6,7],
 [8,9,10,11]]

myIdxs = [[0,2],
 [1,3],
 [0,1]]

result = [[i[j] for j in v] for i, v in zip(myList, myIdxs)]
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[[0, 2], [5, 7], [8, 9]]
```